# When creating animations, how come we start at frame 1, not frame at 0?

Tags: animation

By default it is set to frame 1, not at frame 0, any particular reason why?

Answer (score 5):

It's this way because just about everything else that is indivisible in the world is that way, and for good reason. We start at frame 1 because it's the first frame. Sure 0 could be used, but having 0 as the first frame instead of 1 would be unnecessarily confusing since frame 1 would now not be the first frame and everything would be offset by 1.

It may be easier to understand if you think of a similar situation where you start at one and not zero, such as counting things (which is technically what we are doing here) or book pages.

Comment: Granted individual things are `counted` from 1, but `measurements` are usually done on scales starting at 0. Hours, minutes and seconds start at 0 and 5:30 really means 5h 30min after the beginning of the day. Starting at 1, like for years (1 AD) introduces confusion, leading to the odd y2k events, celebrating the new century/millennium on 1/1/2000, one year before their actual beginning. It's meaningful to start frames at 0 because it's a measurement, even if frames anyway are unreliable markers, since the actual time of the frame start depends on the fps, which can be changed at any time.